# Get current product name in static web template html file on product view page

Tags: magento2, product-page, static-content

I want to get the current product name in static html file which is called in product view page like below file

> app/design/frontend/Vendorname/themename/Aheadworks_AdvancedReviews/web/template/product/view/review/summary/container.html

Answer (score 0):

Create a block

```
namespace Namespace\Module\Block;

class ProductDetails extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $registry;

    public function __construct(   
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    )
    {       
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    public function getCurrentProduct() {
        return $this->registry->registry('current_product');
    }   
}
```

Get product information In your phtml file

```
$currentProduct = $block->getCurrentProduct();
echo $currentProduct->geName();
```

If you want to get in current product information in phtml you can use following code.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$currentProduct = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
echo $currentProduct>getName();
```

**NOTE** : Using Object Manager directly, is not a good practice

Comment: No I need to get product name in static html template not in phtml file like mentioned file in my question

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in phtml:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$currentProduct = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product information
echo $currentProduct>getName();
```

Comment: No I need to get product name in static html template not in phtml file like mentioned file in my question